# UITextField is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have two separate signup and login pages for an app I'm developing. The login page works great, however I'm running into a weird problem for the sign up page. There are 3 separate ViewControllers for the sign up process, with the first one containing the name, email, username and password text fields. You then click through one more ViewController where you add a picture and then have a ViewController that displays all the information and has a "Confirm" button. This button then calls my signUp method where I'm getting the error that NameTF.text is nil when I try to pass it to a String variable. I have tried passing the TextFields data in regularly as well as using:

```
@IBAction func FirstNameTF2(sender: UITextField) {
    firstName = sender.text!
}
```

Edit: Full current code

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
// Sign Up Page 1
@IBOutlet weak var FirstNameTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var LastNameTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var EmailTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var UserNameTF: UITextField!

//Sign Up Page 2
@IBOutlet weak var PasswordTF: UITextField!
// Bday, gender coming

//Sign Up Page 3
// Profile picture coming

func signUp(){
    let user = PFUser()
    let firstName = FirstNameTF.text
    let lastName = LastNameTF.text
    let fullName = firstName! + " " + lastName!
    user.username = UserNameTF.text
    user.password = PasswordTF.text
    user.email = EmailTF.text
    user["name"] = fullName

    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            //let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? NSString
            // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
        } else {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
        }
    }

}


@IBAction func SignUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {
}


}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Describing what you're doing is nice, but to help you we need to know what you're actually doing in code. The example of a single `IBAction` isn't enough for that.

Comment: Yes post all your code. As its hard to know why this Action method is there.

Comment: @Eendje Edited with all my code for that View Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using the same class for your 3 view controllers in IB.  If that is the case, you have to keep in mind that you will have 3 individual and separate instances of you class.   The outlets on one instance will not carry over to another instance.  So, for example, if firstNameTF is connected to the first page and receives a value, this value only exists in that instance and is not accessible to page 2 or page 3 when they are presented.